# Can't find text using special character classes in vim search mode

Tags: regex, vim

Trying to search a string with regex in vim fails when there are whitespace characters.

I want vim to find both

```
<title><![CDATA[formTempoFisio]]></title>
```

as

```
<question><![CDATA[<p>
        <span style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 9pt;">{(strtotime(datInicioFisioAt)-strtotime(datLesao))/60/60/24}</span></p>
]]></question>
```

Note that there is a new line after `<p>` and after `<span style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 9pt;">{(strtotime(datInicioFisioAt)-strtotime(datLesao))/60/60/24}</span></p>` in second case.

I'm using special characters inside a collection. My search regex is:

```
/<!\[CDATA\[[[:alnum:][:space:][:return:][:tab:]]\+\]\]>
```

but vim only finds when there are not new line characters.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try: `\v\<!(.|\n){-}]\>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems.

- `[:space:]` matches all whitespace characters, including `\r` and `\t`, so `[:return:]` and `[:tab:]` are redundant.
- `[:alnum:]` matches ASCII letters and digits. It does not match e.g. `<` or `=` or `"`, so `<span style="` cannot be matched.
- To match across line boundaries, you need to explicitly include `\n` in the character class or prepend `\_`.

You can use the following regex:

```
/<!\[CDATA\[\_.\{-}\]\]>
```

This matches `<![CDATA[`, followed by any character including newline (`\_.`) repeated 0 or more times, but as little as possible (`\{-}`, "non-greedy"), followed by `]]>`.

---

If you want to explicitly list the characters that appear in your second example, it gets more complicated:

```
/<!\[CDATA\[\_[[:alnum:][:space:]<>=":,;{}()\/-]\{-}\]\]>
```

It still doesn't match e.g. `'` or `+`, which could easily appear in code, so there seems little point in restricting the set of allowed characters.